# How to define a new type()

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Something:

    def __init__(self, x, y=0):

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

x is a string and y is a currency number. How can i define a new type such that

```
type(self.y) == Currency
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a new type in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639298/create-a-new-type-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simple classes(no logic, only data), you can also use `dataclasses`. This is available in python 3.7

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Currency:
     value: int
```

For older versions, you can use `namedtuple`

```
from collections import namedtuple

Currency = namedtuple('Currency', ['value'])
```

Comment: In your second snippet, running the namedtuple code and then calling `type(Currency)` returns 'type', not 'Currency'

Comment: That's because, `Currency` is the new type you just defined. You'd use it like `c = Currency(3)`

Comment: Nevermind, I misunderstood. Nice succinct solution!

Comment: none of these solutions worked out for me. I need the type to be asserted to equal currency. so that ```type(Something.y) == Currency```

Comment: The type will be currency if you pass a currency object to Something. You're probably not doing that. Note, you have a default value for `y` as 0. Which would make it an `int`. Your default should also need to be a currency

Comment: that wouldnt work bcs the new class which you want me to create is then separate from the class Something.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say there. What do you mean by separate? All classes are separate. If you want a new type is _has_ to be separate.

Comment: the thing is, the only way this works is if i use a separate class and then call on that class from Something.So like this: ```self.y=Currency(y)``` But what if the Currency class that i create is required to have a ```__repr__ ``` argument which whenever i try ```Something(4)``` it gives me a string. How  would i output the value for ```Something(y)``` as an integer and still get an integer and not a string if my new Currency class has a ```__repr__```

Answer (score 2):

Define a `Currency` class like this:

```
class Currency(object):
     def __init__(self, value):
             self.value = value
```

Then you can create a new variable of type `Currency` like this:

```
y = Currency(3)
```