# How to create and return a new Instance of type T in Python

Tags: python, generics

Is it possible to create a new instance of type T using  generics in python?
I know how to do it in C# and have found plenty of examples but cant find anything for python.
For example:

```
public class Animal<T> where T : ISound, new(){
public T GetInstance()
{
    return new T();
}}
```

Is there a python equivalent to the above C# snippet?

This is what I thought my python code needed to look like:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar('T'

class crud(Generic[T])
   def create(self, endpoint: str, body, files=None) ->T:
      url = self._build_url_str(endpoint)

      res = self.http.post(url, json=body).json()
      return T.__init__(res)
```

But I get TypeError: A single constraint is not allowed.

I google that and what I found didn't work or seemed irelevant.

Also, type T has what it needs to parse the response in the constructor so it has to be parametrized.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a new type in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639298/create-a-new-type-in-python)

Comment: Not at all. My create method should return a new instance of whatever type I gave it to the crud generic superclass

Comment: Does this help? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725868/generics-templates-in-python

Answer (score -2):

As stated in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60984681/14240561), you can do the following, but it is really discouraged:

```
class Animal(Generic[T]):
    def get_instance(self) -> T:
        return self.__orig_class__.__args__[0]()
```